# Ruby URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?) besides encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

I know this is a common error and i'm using a known solution but its still giving me the same error:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://website.com/dirs/filex[a]"

safeurl = URI.parse(URI.encode(url))
...
```

Gives `URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):`

I know its the `[` and `]` characters causing this. But the URI.encode isn't doing anything

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you meant to require uri, not open-uri. Also, [according to the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) you can specify a second parameter with extra characters to encode. Try passing `[]` there.

The code for this solution would be:

```
safeurl = URI.parse(URI.encode(url, "[]"))
```

Comment: requiring `uri` didnt make a difference but passing [] fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue here. I've used this aproach to solve this:

```
require 'cgi'
url = "http://website.com/dirs/filex[a]"

safeurl = URI.parse(CGI.escape(url).gsub("%3A", ":").gsub("%2F", "/"))
```

Instead of requiring uri, I'm using CGI class to escape invalid characters, but the CGI escapes everything, including the colons and forward slashes, so after I'm using gsub to get them back.